# Функция для изменения окончания слов в зависимости от числа в Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, функции, числа

Русский - это не мой родной язык, но постараюсь высказаться.

В упражнении HTML и Javascript, я создал коробку `<input/>`и кнопку для ввода числа. Нажав кнопку `ввести`, абзац `<p>` должен бы показать введённое число и слово "пользователь" в соответствующем падеже, в зависимости от последней цифры. (...)1 пользователь, (...)2 пользователя, (...)5 пользователей, и т.д., за исключением чисел 11-14 (-ей).

Вот моя функция, которая пока не работает:

```js
function func_num() {
  var num, result;
  num = Number(document.getElementById("users_number").value);

  var string = num.toString();
  var lastChar = string.charAt(string.length - 1);

  if (isNaN(num)) {
    result = "Ввод не состоит из цифр.";
  } else if (lastChar == "1" && !(num == 11)) {
    result = num + " пользователь в сети.";
  } else if (lastChar == "2" && !(num == 12)) {
    result = num + " пользователя в сети.";
  } else if (lastChar == "3" && !(num == 13)) {
    result = num + " пользователя в сети.";

    else if (lastChar == "4" && !(num == 14)) {
      result = num + " пользователя в сети.";
    } else {
      result = num + " пользователей в сети.";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }
```

```html
<input id="users_number" />
<button onclick="func_num()">Ввести</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Не умею найти, что неправильно. Если честно, механизм работает когда переменная num  - статическое число. Например, **num = 24**, без коробки input и без сосуда функции для переменных и условий: страница HTML производит ожидаемый результат, с числом изменяемым в редакторе HTML, из которого следует склонённое слово "пользователь". Но когда стараюсь вернуть интерактивность переменной num, заключённой в функции - **num = Number.document(getElementbyId("users_number").value)** - то функция не работает. Печатаю число в коробку input, могу нажать кнопку "Ввести", но ожидаемый текст "xx ползовател.ь/я/ей" не появляется.

[image: Результат вышеупомянутой, не работающей функции]

Вот результат статического числа:

[image: здесь переменные "corda" и "ultcar" (от португальского языка) заменяют соответственно "string" и "lastChar"]

[image: Результат, который ожидается от полной функции с коробкой ввода]

Можете вы мне помочь? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А 111 пользователей может быть в сети?

Comment: Ох, спасибо, что предупредили о числах, кончающих по (...)11. Наверное, мой вышеупомянутый код (после поправок) производить "111 пользователя". Но я нашёл простое решение:

var string = num.toString();
    var lastChar = string.charAt(string.length-1);
    var penulChar = string.charAt(string.length-2); 

if (lastChar == "1" && !(penulChar == "1")) {
        result = num + " пользователь в сети.";
}

(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте какой-либо отладчик, например Chrome DevTools, доступный в браузере Chrome по кнопке F12.

В вашем примере отсутствует `}` перед строкой `else if (lastChar == "4" && !(num == 14)) {`

В остальном он работает. Еще удобный сайт для моделирования - с Вашим примером - [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/9tvzhxu8/)

Comment: Ого... да, я забыл переписать сюда ту скобку. Но даже если синтаксис полностью правильна, страница не работала... по крайней мере в Яндекс браузере. Там я тестировал свою страницу .html; по видимости, это проблема браузера а не проблема моего синтаксиса. Спасибо за помощь и сайт тестирования!

Answer (score 5):

```js
function enumerate (num, dec) {
    if (num > 100) num = num % 100;
    if (num <= 20 && num >= 10) return dec[2];
    if (num > 20) num = num % 10;
    return num === 1 ? dec[0] : num > 1 && num < 5 ? dec[1] : dec[2];
}

document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
  let count = +document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = count + " " + enumerate(count, ["пользователь", "пользователя", "пользователей"]) + " в сети";
  return false
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input">
  <button>Ввод</button>
</form>
<div id="users"></div>
```